# Size of Primitive data types

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

On what exactly does the size of a primitive data type like `int` depend on?

- Compiler
- Processor
- Development Environment

Or is it a combination of these or other factors?
An explanation on the reason of the same will be really helpful.

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion..I meant to ask about Primitive data type like int and not regarding PODs, I do understand PODs can include structure and with structure it is a whole different ball game with padding coming in to the picture.
I have corrected the Q, the edit note here should ensure the answers regarding POD don't look irrelevant.

Comment: Do you mean *primitive* (or *built-in*) types, or actually POD types (structs, unions)?

Comment: @Alex, @Als: An important question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ : size of int, long, etc...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/c-size-of-int-long-etc)

Answer (score 9):

I think there are two parts to this question:

1. What sizes primitive types are *allowed* to be.
   This [is specified by the C and C++ standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/c-size-of-int-long-etc/589684#589684): the types have allowed minimum value ranges they must have, which implicitly places a lower bound on their size *in bits* (e.g. `long` must be at least 32 bit to comply with the standard).
   The standards do not specify the size in bytes, because the [definition of the byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437470/type-to-use-to-represent-a-byte-in-ansi-c89-90-c/437640#437640) is up to the implementation, e.g. `char` is byte, but byte size (`CHAR_BIT` macro) may be 16 bit.
2. The actual size as defined by the implementation.
   This, as other answers have already pointed out, is dependent on the implementation: the compiler. And the compiler implementation, in turn, is heavily influenced by the target architecture. So it's plausible to have two compilers running on the same OS and architecture, but having different size of `int`. The only assumption you can make is the one stated by the standard (given that the compiler implements it).
   There also may be additional ABI requirements (e.g. fixed size of enums).

Comment: It should be noted that the vast majority of implementations for major systems attempt to adhere to an existing ABI specification which specifies the sizes and format of most or all types in order to facilitate compatibility across different tools or different versions of the same tool.

Comment: Compilers or implementations, try to use sizes that are most efficient with the platform.  On 16-bit only platforms, the compiler may use 16-bits for a `char`, because that is efficient with the processor.

Comment: @Thomas : the size of char is defined by the Standard itself, which is 1. Please see my post.

Comment: @Nawaz, `sizeof char` is always one, however `CHAR_BIT` may be >= 8, so the actual size of `char` in bits will be greater than 8.

Comment: @Alex : then what does sizeof(char)==1 mean if bits can be greater than 8?

Comment: @R.. I was trying to dig up some more on these, but wasn't sure. Can you give an example of an ABI that explicitly specifies the size of a C data type? All requirements I can find are things like alignment requirements of n-bit data (without explicitly referencing actual C data types).

Comment: @Alex : what do you mean by correct? that you're correct? or me?

Comment: @Nawaz oh I misread you. It means that char is byte (a minimum addressable memory unit), but not necessarily an octet. Read my linked answer.

Comment: The SVR4 i386 ABI specifies the size of all types, as does the LSB (Linux Standard Base) ABI for i386. You can find plenty more from various proprietary Unix vendors. And of course the Windows ABI has particular type sizes.

Comment: @Alex : CHAR_BIT is always 8. It's defined by the Standard itself. Who says you that it's value could be other than 8?

Comment: @Nawaz, nope, the C standard does not required it, it only implies it should be at least 8 (because of allowed char value range). Only POSIX requires it to be exactly 8-bit. Here is an excerpt from C99 standard commentary doc: "C is not wedded to an 8-bit byte, although this value is implicit in a large percentage of source written in it. [...] Some DSP chips have a 16- or 32-bit character type (this has more to do with addressability issues than character set sizes)."

Comment: @Alex : that's interesting quotation. could you tell me the section too so that I can see myself and can read the relevant stuffs?

Comment: @Nawaz This one was from the commentary. In the actual standard it's in section 5.2.4.2.1(1): "The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives. [...] Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign." Also in Annex E: Implementation Limits.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it depends on Compiler. Compiler in turns usually depends on the architecture, processor, development environment etc because it takes them into account.  So you may say it's a combination of all. **But I would NOT say that. I would say, Compiler**, since on the same machine you may have different sizes of POD and *built-in* types, if you use different compilers. Also note that your source code is input to the compiler, so it's the compiler which makes **final** decision of the sizes of POD and built-in types. However, it's also true that this decision is influenced by the underlying architecture of the target machine. After all, the real ***useful*** compiler **has to** emit *efficient* code that eventually runs on the machine you target.

Compilers provides `options` too. Few of them might effect sizes also!

---

## EDIT:  What Standards say,

Size of `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` is defined by C++ Standard itself! Sizes of all other types are defined by the compiler.

C++03 Standard $5.3.3/1 says,

> sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and
>   sizeof(unsigned char) are 1; the
>   result of sizeof applied to **any other**
>   fundamental type (3.9.1) is
>   implementation-defined. [Note: in
>   particular,sizeof(bool) and
>   sizeof(wchar_t) are
>   implementation-defined.69)

C99 Standard ($6.5.3.4) also itself defines the size of `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` to be 1, but leaves the size of other types to be defined by the compiler!

---

EDIT:

I found this C++ FAQ chapter really good. The entire chapter. It's very tiny chapter though. :-)

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html

---

Also read the comments below, there are some good arguments!

Comment: @Nawaz: Agree and think so too...Just need a conclusive Inference! :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, it only depends on the compiler. The CPU just influences what layout would be more efficient, but the compiler can, in principle, do anything it likes. It doesn't have to respect the CPU's alignment requirements, register sizes or anything else, as long as it generates code that works.

Comment: @jalf: Although some architectures are really unforgiving when it comes to data alignment (e.g. IA64).

Comment: @In silico: that just means that the compiler has to generate extra code to handle it. (It could do two aligned loads, then combine the result in registers. Expensive, sure, but it allows the compiler to do unaligned loads even on CPUs that don't support it directly)

Comment: @jalf: Ah, I see what you mean. I was objecting to the statement "It doesn't have to respect the CPU's alignment requirements."

Comment: @jalf : Since compiler is built upon the underlying architecture, then you cannot really say it doesn't effect it's choices! It's a matter of expression only, if you say it depends on the compiler ONLY, by that it only means that if compiler wants then it can implement sizeof(int) = 128. But it doesn't, since it respects the architecture! In fact, it has to respect the architecture if it wants to emit efficient code!

Comment: @Nawaz: Now you're moving the goalposts. No one said anything about *efficient code*. Of course, a compiler trying to generate *fast* code will have to take the CPU into account. But the OP didn't ask about efficiency, and a compiler which is willing to take a performance hit *could* define `sizeof(int)` to be 15 and its alignment to be 5. It'd be slow, but the compiler could just generate code to make it work.

Comment: @In silico: yeah that was a bit misleading. Of course the code generated by the compiler has to respect the CPU's requirements, but the C++ data types don't have to map directly to the CPU's registers or alignment requirements.

Comment: @jalf : I'm sure the topic starter doesn't want to know about something which doesn't exist in the real world. All I'm saying is, in the real world of programming, the underlying architecture does have influence on the compiler's choices, just like your bank-balance influences your choices of things you buy in a supermarket. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: I never denied that. I just felt it was worth giving an *accurate* answer: one which *both* mentions what will happen *in the real world* due to efficiency concerns, and what is actually *required* by the standard.

Comment: He did ask what **exactly** the size of a POD depended on. And the only *exact* answer is "the compiler, and nothing else".

Comment: @jalf: the world is not discontinuous as you seem to think. A regular guy may say, child behavior depends on his upbringing, while a biologist might say it depends on his gene also. Both are correct as long as they do not contradict each other!

Comment: How exactly do "it depends on the compiler only" and "it depends on compiler and CPU" not contradict each others? If I asked **exactly** what child behavior depends on, then both of these answers would be incorrect, because it depends on more than one factor.

Comment: @jalf : yes, the existence of the compiler itself depends on the machine it runs on. So anything compiler does, or is able to do, is defined by the machine it runs on. Just like you cannot fly, since the gene and other things you're made of, doesn't support 'flying'!

Comment: @Nawaz: not quite, because *any* compiler can be made to run on *any* turing-complete CPU, and generate code for *any* turing-complete CPU. So what you're really saying is that "it depends on the compiler and on having a computer", which... isn't even true, because I could write it all out on paper if I had the time and patience.

Comment: @jalf : this is awesome *"I could write it all out on paper if I had the time and patience"* ... which implies that it doesn't depend even on the compiler; it entirely depends on the author of the compiler, who makes the *actual* decision of the size of the built-in types and POD.

Comment: The size of intrinsic types is not defined by the standard; the range of valid values is defined.  The exception is `char` which has a size of 1 (measurement defined by compiler).

Comment: @Thomas : who says it's defined by the standard?

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about the size of a *primitive* type like `int`, I'd say it depends on the factor you cited.

The compiler/environment couple (where environment often means OS) is surely a part of it, since the compiler can map the various "sensible" sizes on the builtin types in different ways for various reasons: for example, compilers on x86_64 Windows will usually have a 32 bit `long` and a 64 bit `long long` to avoid breaking code thought for plain x86; on x86_64 Linux, instead, `long` is usually 64 bit because it's a more "natural" choice and apps developed for Linux are generally more architecture-neutral (because Linux runs on a much greater variety of architectures).

The processor surely matters in the decision: `int` should be the "natural size" of the processor, usually the size of the general-purpose registers of the processor. This means that it's the type that will work faster on the current architecture. `long` instead is often thought as a type which trades performance for an extended range (this is rarely true on regular PCs, but on microcontrollers it's normal).

If in instead you're also talking about `struct`s & co. (which, if they respect some rules, *are* `POD`), again the compiler and the processor influence their size, since they are made of builtin types and of the appropriate padding chosen by the compiler to achieve the best performance on the target architecture.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented under @Nawaz's answer, it technically depends solely on the compiler.

The compiler is just tasked with taking valid C++ code, and outputting valid machine code (or whatever language it targets).

So a C++ compiler *could* decide to make an `int` have a size of 15, and require it to be aligned on 5-byte boundaries, and it *could* decide to insert arbitrary padding between the variables in a POD. Nothing in the standard prohibits this, and it could still generate working code.

It'd just be much slower.

So in practice, compilers take some hints from the system they're running on, in two ways:
- the CPU has certain preferences: for example, it may have 32-bit wide registers, so making an `int` 32 bits wide would be a good idea, and it usually requires variables to be naturally aligned (a 4-byte wide variable must be aligned on an address divisible by 4, for example), so a *sensible* compiler respects these preferences because it yields faster code.
- the OS may have some influence too, in that if it uses another ABI than the compiler, making system calls is going to be needlessly difficult.

But those are just practical considerations to make life a bit easier for the programmer or to generate faster code. They're not *required*.

The compiler has the final word, and it *can* choose to completely ignore both the CPU and the OS. As long as it generates a working executable with the semantics specified in the C++ standard.

Comment: The compiler has to define the sizes of the types in order to meet the ranges specified in the Standard.  For an 8-bit (octet) platform, the compiler would need at least two octects to meet the range specification for an integer.

Comment: Of course. That's what I said in the last paragraph. It has to generate an executable which follows the semantics of C++ (which, among other things, specify minimum sizes for certain data types)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation (compiler).

[`Implementation-defined behavior`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) means unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made.

Comment: FWIW, the compiler must allocate enough bits to allocate the ranges specified in the C language standard (specification).  If the compiler wants to use 1024 bits for an integer, it can and still be compiliant with the standard.

Answer (score 0):

A `struct` can also be POD, in which case you can explicity control potential padding between members with `#pragma pack` on some compilers.