# C pointers and bit setting question

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

As background to this question this was a test program I wrote to investigate some strange behavior we were seeing in a messaging program I work on. We have various structures that use bit flags to hold states about the messages, some of the flags use char, some use shorts. A utility we have to dump the messages to flat files was using a char* on these flag values to extract the settings, hence my deliberate use of a different pointer on flag2.

When this program is run on AIX UNIX 6.1 why is the output:

2 set
4 set
8 set
16 set
64 set

What happened to values 1 and 32 ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SET(x,y) y |= (x)
#define UNSET(x,y) y &= (~x)

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    unsigned char *g;
    unsigned short *h;
    unsigned long *i;

    char flag1; 
    short flag2; 
    long flag3;

    g = (char*) &flag2;

    SET(1, flag2);
    if ( 1 & *g )
        printf("1 set\n");
    UNSET(1, flag2);

    SET(2, flag2);
    if ( 2 & *g )
        printf("2 set\n");
    UNSET(2, flag2);

    SET(4, flag2);
    if ( 4 & *g )
        printf("4 set\n");
    UNSET(4, flag2);

    SET(8, flag2);
    if ( 8 & *g )
        printf("8 set\n");
    UNSET(8, flag2);

    SET(16, flag2);
    if ( 16 & *g )
        printf("16 set\n");
    UNSET(16, flag2);

    SET(32, flag2);
    if ( 32 & *g )
        printf("32 set\n");
    UNSET(32, flag2);

    SET(64, flag2);
    if ( 64 & *g )
        printf("64 set\n");
    UNSET(64, flag2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to explicitly initialize `flag2` to 0.

Comment: flag2 is short but you are casting a pointer to it to char*, use short* instead (g should be also of type short then).

Comment: I run the program on HP UX and it does not print anything at all, however when I run the same program on Fedora, it works.

Comment: why are you using a char pointer on a short ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AIX is a big endian architecture, that means that `g` points to the most significant bytes of `flag`. This means any changes to the least significant bytes are invisible to `g`.

`flag2` is also never initialized so it will contain some arbirary values. So it turns out your think some bit setting worked when it was just the arbirary values that was there in the beginning.

If you run on a little endian machine like x86, things should behave as expected.

Comment: Not only because it is big endian, but because short and char happen to be different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things that could be the problem.

1. You aren't initializing `flag2`
2. You might want to cast `g= (short *
   )  &flag2`, because if you cast to
   char you won't necessarily be
   getting a reference to the least
   significant 8 bits.

Comment: But he sets every bit *before* checking its state

Comment: He may be checking different memory locations, *g might refer to the most significant 8 bits rather than the least significant which he is expecting.

Comment: @BlackBear: `SET(1, flag2)` presumably sets a bit in a different char from the one that `1 & *g` tests.

Comment: @bobbogo, @eric: yeah, I missed that detail. :)

Comment: Yea that's what I'm expecting, which is why neglecting initialization isn't hidden as it should be.

Comment: P.S. `g= (short * ) &flag2` isn't going to give you "a reference to the least significant 8 bits."

Comment: No, it gives you a reference to the entire memory location, which is instead of g= (char * ) &flag2 which will give you the most significant 8 bits. I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia's [pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29):

> A 2005 draft of the C standard
>   requires that casting a pointer
>   derived from one type to one of
>   another type should maintain the
>   alignment correctness for both types
>   (6.3.2.3 Pointers, par. 7):[3]

```
char *external_buffer = "abcdef";
int *internal_data;

internal_data = (int *)external_buffer;  // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR if "the resulting pointer
                                         // is not correctly aligned"
```

Bottom line: ***use the right pointer type***

The behavior might work as expected, but isn't guaranteed.

C++03 Standard $5.3.3/1 says,

> ```
> sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1; the
> ```
>
> result of sizeof applied to any other
>   fundamental type (3.9.1) is
>   implementation-defined. [Note: in
>   particular,sizeof(bool) and
>   sizeof(wchar_t) are
>   implementation-defined.69)

Look at this: [C++ Size of primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562249/size-of-primitive-data-types)