# Getting the least significant byte

Tags: c++

I haven't tested on a big endian processor but would this always give me least significant byte?

```
int i = 12345678;
unsigned char c = static_cast<unsigned char>(i);
```

Comment: (meta) If you use static_cast you shouldn't mark the question as C. I won't retag it because I think it's better you do it (so you learn tag-etiquette :-) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this will always give you the least-significant byte.  The C++ spec (§4.7/2) guarantees that narrowing conversions always discard the most-significant bytes by giving back the smallest value congruent to the original integer, modulo 2<sup>n</sup>, where n is the number of bits in the target type.

That said, there's no guarantee that an `unsigned char` is a single byte.  All that's guaranteed is that `sizeof(char) == 1`.  However, if you treat a byte as the smallest memory unit capable of holding a character, then this should work just fine.

Comment: @templatetypedef: `unsigned char` is also single byte. See  $5.3.3/1

Comment: @Nawaz but the standard doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: @user32344: I also posted the reference!

Comment: See this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562249/size-of-primitive-data-types/4562283#4562283

Comment: @Nawaz- Hmmm... this is interesting because the C++ spec defines a byte as the smallest addressable unit *in the C++ memory model*, but it's possible for someone to make a compliant implementation of C++ in which a C++ "byte" would be two bytes on the native system, as long as everything was consistent.  This would be a pathologically evil edge case designed specifically to prove a point, though.

Comment: @templatetypedef: upto C++03, C++ doesn't has it's own memory model. Whatever it has maps directly to the native one. So what you said *"in which a C++ "byte" would be two bytes on the native system"* doesn't seem to be true!

Comment: @Nawaz- There's a section ($1.7) that defines the C++ memory model.  It's not like Java's rigidly-specified model, but it says nothing whatsoever about what a "byte" is other than it's the smallest unit of storage and that it has an address.  It never mentions anything about mapping to the native system; to the best of my knowledge nothing in the C++ spec talks about "the native system."

Comment: @templatetypedef: the same section talks about C++ byte being same as the smallest addressable unit which is also the definition of "byte" on a native system. Native system doesn't define it differently, as far as I know.

Comment: A char is always one byte, by definition. What the standard doesn't say is that a byte has to be 8 bits! It can be larger.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the following also work?

```
int i = 12345678;
unsigned char c = (i % 256);
```

or

```
int i = 12345678;
unsigned char c = (i & 255);
```