# C: long long always 64 bit?

Tags: c

If i'm using long longs in my code, can i absolutely 100% guarantee that they will have 64 bits no matter what machine the code is run on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size of Primitive data types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562249/size-of-primitive-data-types)

Answer (score 15):

No, C99 standard says that it will have **at least** 64 bits. So it could be more than that at some point I guess. You could use `int64_t` type if you need 64bits always assuming you have `stdint.h` available (standard in C99).

```
#include <stdint.h>
int64_t your_i64;
```

Comment: `int64_t` must be provided if the implementation has a type that fits its requirements -- but it's (at least theoretically) possible that no such type exists, in which case `int64_t` won't be defined.

Comment: `int_least64_t` **must be provided by C99 implementations**; this guarantees 64 or more bits

Comment: @pmg long long also guarantees **at least** 64 bits. That was the problem. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can test if your compiler is C99 complying with respect to numbers in the preprocessor with this

```
# if (~0U < 18446744073709551615U)
#  error "this should be a large positive value, at least ULLONG_MAX >= 2^{64} - 1"
# endif
```

This works since all unsigned values (in the preprocessor) are required to be the same type as `uintmax_t` and so `0U` is of type `uintmax_t` and `~0U`, `0U-1` and `-1U` all are the maximum representable number.

If this test works, chances are high that `unsigned long long` is in fact `uintmax_t`.

For a valid expression after the preprocessing phase to test this with the real types do

```
unsigned long long has_ullong_max[-1 + 2*((0ULL - 1) >= 18446744073709551615ULL)];
```

This does the same sort of trick but uses the postfix `ULL` to be sure to have constants of type `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 0):

They are guaranteed to be a minimnum of 64 bits. It's theoretically possible that they could be larger (e.g., 128 bits) though I'm reasonably they're only 64 bits on anything currently available.

Comment: On llp64 memory model compilers, it would have been convenient if long long int was bumped up to 128 bits.

Comment: I'd be surprised if no DSP with an non power of two size word is available and DSP have usually a C compiler.  And then historical machines are a little (not much) more alive than often though: PDP-10 (36 bits processors, it has a port of gcc somewhere on the net and I think it used 72 bit long long) were still used as embedded processor in some network hardware last time I've looked at, and Unisys is still selling 36 bits and 48 bit machines -- I don't know if they have a C compilers for them or not.

Comment: @AProgrammer: I believe Unisys has a C compiler, but at least the last time I looked, it only attempted to conform with C90 rather than C99, so I'm not at all sure it had long-long at all. I suppose my wording was ambiguous: while gcc is certainly available, PDP-10s haven't been for quite a while.

Comment: @Jerry, If I was not clear, the practical cases I'd care of would be DSP, not PDP-10 (XKL still sold them in 1997 and I think they still are using them internally) nor Unisys machines.

Comment: @AProgrammer: I'm less certain about DSPs. AD SigmaDSP, for example, are 28/56-bit processors, so the obvious choice for them would be 112 bits for `long long`, but at least the last time I used them, they didn't provide that. TigerSHARC use 64-bit long longs. I believe TI C5000 and C6000 use 64-bit long long as well. There are other vendors, but...

Answer (score 0):

With

```
#if CHAR_BIT * sizeof (long long) != 64
   #pragma error "long long is not 64 bits"
#endif
```

or some equivalent.

Based on comment: if you want to support compilers where sizeof can't be used in the pre-processor, see this thread:

http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread13553.html

Something like this:

```
 char longlongcheck[(sizeof(long long) * CHAR_BIT) == 64]; // won't compile if the expression is 0.
```

Comment: You can't use `sizeof` in a preprocessor expression (officially anyway -- some compilers allow it, but it's an extension).

Comment: For those compilers there's a trick with making an array with the size that is illegal if it doesn't match.  Will find and post.

Comment: tricks with `sizeof` are unfortunately not guaranteed to work on bizarre machines with padding bits. See my answer for variants that don't depend on this.

Comment: Umm, `#if LLONG_MIN != -0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF-1` is the easy and simple way (this also checks for twos complement at the same time, which you'll almost surely want to ensure if you care about the number of bits).