# Project Euler 8 in C, working with 4 digits and fails for 13 digits?

Tags: c

I have coded the problem in C. When I run the code to find the solution for the four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product I get the correct answer. But with the 13 adjacent digits I am always getting the wrong answer (2039787520), can someone point it out where I am wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

//Storing the 1000 digits
char number_array[] =   "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
                        "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
                        "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
                        "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
                        "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
                        "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
                        "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
                        "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
                        "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
                        "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
                        "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
                        "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
                        "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
                        "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
                        "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
                        "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
                        "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
                        "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
                        "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
                        "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

int main(void){
  int length = sizeof(number_array);
  int64_t max_product = 0;
  int i, j;

   for( i = 0; i <= length - 13; i++){

     int64_t  product = 1;

      //Going through 13 consecutive digits for each digit in the char 
       array
      for(j = 0; j < 13; j++){
        printf("product -- > %d and number -- > %d\n",product ,
        (number_array[i+j] - 0x30));

        // finding the product
        product = product * (number_array[i + j] - 0x30);

      //if product is zero skipping the process
        if(product == 0){break;}
      }

     printf("product -- > %I64d\n", product);

     //checking for the max product
     if(product > max_product){
       max_product = product;
     }

   }

  printf("max_product -- > %I64d\n", max_product);
}

`
```

Comment: do not use magic numbers like 0x30 or 48. Use `'0'` instead. That describes the intention clearly and is more correct because the codepoint for `0` is not 48 in all character sets

Comment: and there are already a lot of questions about project Euler 8 like http://stackoverflow.com/q/8681642/995714, http://stackoverflow.com/q/20710051/995714

Comment: The code invokes undefined behaviour for passing wrong parameter types to `printf` varargs. You seem to be aware about the wrong types, but your format strings are completely wrong. Use `inttypes.h` macros and correct them.

Comment: It's hard to know where you error in logic lies given the dearth of information you have provided. Your logic shows you read `987` of `1000` with your `i` loop (indexes `0` - `986`) and then for each element in your `j` loop you read `13`. (indexes `987` - `999`). You provided no way we can know if that is anywhere near right. It may be, it may not, but we have no way to know either way...

Comment: `sizeof number_array` includes the null terminator in the size

Answer (score 2):

I replaced `int64_t` type with `long long` and printed the value using the `%lld` format specifier with no other changes to your program and it works. The answer is correct.
For demo [click here](https://ideone.com/pcr5ri).

Be warned though. The answer to the Project Euler question 8 is there in the link as well. If you want to enjoy finding the answer yourselves, you better not scroll down too much in the page whose link is above.

**Edit:** As a comment made me realize after a bit of searching, `long long` is guaranteed to be *at least* 64 bits ([as explained in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5221615/5375464)) but needn't be 64 bits. (ie, Could be more but not less).

If the `long long` won't do, you can use the unsigned version of `int64_t` which is `uint64_t`. This is *guaranteed* to be 64 bits. Nothing more. Nothing less.
Like this:

```
uint64_t max_product;
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", max_product);
```

[Click here](https://ideone.com/9p6Nzg) for the demo with `uint64_t`.

Comment: `long long` is not guaranteed to have more than 64 bits. And for almost all current PC/server implementations it has not.

Comment: @Olaf Gee, I didn't know `long long` wasn't 64 bits on most systems. In fact, I thought the exact opposite. All I've ever worked with is gcc. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: You should read my comment carefully again. It did not say it has not 64 bits! And I definitively did not say it is guaranteed to have only 32 bits asthat's plain wrong, don't put words in my mouth. Please read the standard if you doubt me. `int64_t` is - otoh - guaranteed to have exactly 64 bits like `uint64_t`. That's the idea about the fixed width types.

Comment: @Olaf When you say there is no __guarantee__ for `long long` to be 64 bits, did you mean it could be? Meaning many systems are probably having `long long` of size 64b but we can't rely on them being so?

Comment: last try: I never said "there is no guarantee for long long **to be** 64 bits"! **Please** read my comment once more! Precision is a vital part of programming! And read about the standard integer types!

Comment: @J...S use the Ctrl+K / `{}` button to indent a code block.