# what does it mean to bitwise left shift an unsigned char with 16

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

i am reading a .cpp file containing a `unsigned char` variable, it's trying the bitwise left shift 16 bits, since an `unsigned char` is composed of 8 bits, left shift 16 bits will erase all the bits and fill it with eight 0s.

`unsigned char byte=0xff; byte << 16;`

Comment: The value of the expression is not assigned.

Comment: As written, the compiler will optimize the shift operation away as doing nothing.  What was the real code?

Comment: you may want to look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437470/type-to-use-to-represent-a-byte-in-ansi-c89-90-c

Comment: All built-in operators work on objects of at least int size (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5563131/14065). Thus: `sizeof(byte << 16) == sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you shift a value,

```
unsigned char x = ...;
int y = x << 16;
```

The type of `x` is promoted to `int` if `unsigned char` fits in an `int` (most systems), or to `unsigned` if `unsigned char` does not fit in an `int` (rare<sup>1</sup>).  As long as your `int` is 25 bits wide or wider, then no data will be discarded<sup>2</sup>.

Note that this is completely unrelated to the fact that `16` has type `int`.

```
/* All three are exactly equivalent */
x << 16;
x << 16u;
x << (unsigned char) 16;
```

**Source:** from n1516 (C99 draft):

§6.5.7 paragraph 3: Bitwise Shift Operators

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is
>   that of the promoted left operand.

§6.3.1.1 paragraph 2: Boolean, characters, and integers

> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
>   bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned
>   int. These are called the integer promotions.

**Footnotes:**

<sup>1</sup>: Some DSP chips as well as certain Cray supercomputers are known to have `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`.  This simplifies design of the processor's load-store unit at the cost of additional memory consumption.

<sup>2</sup>: If your left shift is promoted to `int` and then overflows the `int`, this is undefined behavior (demons may fly out your nose).  By comparison, overflowing an `unsigned` is always well-defined, so bit shifts *should* usually be done on `unsigned` types.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborate explanation. Though i am still confused about the memory it may accidentally overwrite after promoting the `unsigned char` to `int`

Comment: @leomayleomay: That's not how it works.  If you assign an `int` to an `unsigned char` variable, then the `int` is converted.  (This isn't assembly language, after all.)

Comment: so the bitwise left shift here (16 to the left) will make the variable in question to be 0, right?

Comment: If you assign `x = x << 16`, then on most systems, this is the same as `x = 0`.

Comment: I find this behavior very surprising.
I encountered such a behavior using IAR CSTAT static analysis tool for the following code:
    unsigned short BE2LE16(unsigned short x) { return ((x<<8) | (x>>8));}
and couldn't figure it out until your detailed answer.

Thank you and IAR so much!

Answer (score 1):

If `char` fits inside `int`, it will be promoted to an `int` and the result will be as you expect. If that is not the case it is undefined behavior according to the standard, and will probably emit a compile warning. From the standard:

`The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.`

Comment: It will never cause undefined behavior if `char` cannot fit in `int`, since it must therefore fit inside `unsigned int`, and shifts on `unsigned int` are never undefined.  Only shifts on signed integers are undefined, and only if the mathematical result cannot be represented by the type.  For example, `1 << 16` is undefined if an `int` is 16 bits.

Comment: The integer promotions are indeed performed, which means that the behaviour is only undefined if `unsigned char` is promoted to `int` rather than `unsigned int` and the shift would produce a value that cannot be represented in an `int`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Even `0 << 16` is undefined behaviour if `int` is 16 bits though, because of the constraint noted in this answer.