# What determines the size of primitive data types?

Tags: c++, c, memory, types

For one of my C++ programming assignments, I have to consider the size of an integer variable while designing the program. I read around the internet, and most places say "The size of an integer is dependent on the platform."  I'm unclear about what this means, so I'm asking here.

1. What determines the size of a primitive data type?

   - processor architecture (may be instruction set size).
   - Operation system
   - Compiler
   - Combination of above.
2. What is the reason to choose an integer to have a size of `2 byte`s in some systems, and `4 byte`s in others? Is there any reason it cannot proceed with 2 byte anymore?

Comment: "Is there any reason it cannot proceed with 2 byte anymore?"  Certainly it _can_ stay with 2 bytes, but another size is often chosen for performance.  Had C stuck with the "first" integer size circa 1970s, we might be using 18-bit or who knows what.  It is C adaptability that has made it a 40+ year language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What determines the size of a primitive data type?

It depends on Compiler. Compiler in turns usually depends on the architecture, processor, development environment etc because it takes them into account. So you may say it's a combination of all.

> What is the reason to choose an integer to have a size of 2 bytes in some systems, and 4 bytes in others? Is there any reason it cannot proceed with 2 byte anymore?

The C++ standard does not specify the size of integral types in bytes, but it specifies minimum ranges they must be able to hold. You can infer minimum size in bits from the required range. You can infer minimum size in bytes from that and the value of the `CHAR_BIT` macro that [defines the number of bits in a byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437470/type-to-use-to-represent-a-byte-in-ansi-c89-90-c/437640#437640) (in all but the most obscure platforms it's 8, and it can't be less than 8).

Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589684/2589776) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

> whats the platform they means here.

Usually, it means the combination of operating system, compiler, and some special options of compiler.

> what cause to decide the primitive data type sizes.

That would be 'Combination of above.'

---

By the way, this is called 'memory model' or 'data model' (not sure which one is the correct term), you could learn more about it from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit

Answer (score 1):

It seems your first question has been answered already so I'll take a stab at the second one:

> What is the reason to choose an integer to have a size of 2 bytes in some systems, and 4 bytes in others? Is there any reason it cannot proceed with 2 bytes anymore?

This boils down to the opinions of the designers of an architecture (or compiler, etc.). Very often, memory addresses are represented as `unsigned integer` data types. So you get this interesting history of `integer` sizes that reflect the size of an address in an operating system. That is, it's really no coincidence that:

```
cout << "Unsigned short: " << sizeof(unsigned short) << endl;
cout << "Unsigned int: " << sizeof(unsigned int) << endl;
cout << "Unsigned long: " << sizeof(unsigned long) << endl;
```

Produces the following output on most systems:

```
Unsigned short: 2
Unsigned int: 4
Unsigned long: 8
```

Because a byte is 8 bits, you get the following sizes:

- Unsigned short: 16-bit
- Unsigned int: 32-bit
- Unsigned long: 64-bit

You can make a good bet that if we get to 128-bit operating systems, there will be a data type (maybe `unsigned long long`?) that consists of 16 bytes.

So it's history in a sense, but Why would an architect decide on these sizes to begin with?
Well a few reasons:

1. "It's big enough" Computer Scientists are fond of doing only as much as they need to, so an `integer` data type any bigger would likely be wasteful in most use cases because people simply don't need to count that high with a primitive data type.
2. "It's as big as we can get" You'd like an `integer` to fit entirely within a single register, so the size is usually limited by hardware (registers being only one example).

I'm sure there are other reasons that smarter, more experienced StackOverflow members can give :-)

Comment: In some compilers, `sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)`.  There is no guarantee that `sizeof(long) > sizeof(int)`, but the C++ standard does dictate that `sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

In C the size of int is 4 bytes in gcc(GNU collection of compilers) and 2 bytes in borland and turbo c compiler. The last two compiler is specific for windows and and gcc compiler is the compiler for Linux OS. 
The size of primitive data types is based on compiler and these compiler is basically specific for specific OS. I personally preferred gcc compiler over other compilers because it support lots of features according to the definition of C language. One of the example is null pointer. If you declare a null pointer in gcc and try to access this in gcc it gives you error but turbo c allows to use it no error.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` has not been 2 in Borland compilers since the old days of 16bit OSes.  In 32bit and 64bit OSes, `sizeof(int)` is 4. And FYI, the latest C++Builder from Embarcadero (Borland's successor) has C++ compilers for OSX and iOS, and Android in the near future.