# Ambiguous Output generated using Pointer dereferencing?

Tags: c, pointers, output, dereference

I encountered a following program and was not able to understand how is the output coming to be `-109 1683`.How is the output coming out to be so?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
{
 int k = 1683;
 char *a = (char *)&k;
 int *l  = &k;
 printf("%d " , *a);
 printf("%d" , *l);
  }
 Output is : -109 1683
```

How does dereferencing the pointer `a` give me `-109`?

I expected it to read first byte of the four byte integer .

`1683` in binary representation is `00000000 00000000 00000110 10010011`.So reading first byte means output should be `0 1683`. What is happening behind the scenes , I heard something concerning to architecture endianness , but could not able to follow it.

Comment: Thats because of converting pointer to int to pointer to char. Notice that integer is 4-byte length, and char is 1-byte length.

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: Can you step by step explain me , why is it coming -109 .

Comment: The first byte is `10010011` not `00000000` on little endian

Comment: There is no "pointer `p`"

Comment: Except for the choice of constant (1234 vs 1683), the code in the two questions is functionally equivalent, down to having the same bug of not ending the output with a newline.  The basic issue is the same.  You're lucky you didn't get a zero from the `char *` variable; had you been working on a big-endian machine, that is what you'd have got.  You might also have gotten 146 as the output if the plain `char` type was unsigned — clearly, on your machine, plain `char` is signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something like ,

```
int k = 1683 ;
int *l = &k;
```

If You Dereference Pointer `l` then it will correctly read integer bytes. Because You declared it to be pointer to `int` . It will know how many bytes to read by `sizeof()` operator. Generally size of `int` is `4 bytes` (for 32/64-bit platforms) but it is machine dependent that is why it will use `sizeof()` operator to know correct size and will read so .Now For Your Code

```
 int k = 1683;
 char *a = &k;
 int *l  = &k;
```

Now `pointer p` points to `y` but we have declared it to be pointer to a `char` so it will only read one byte or whatever byte char is of .
`1683` in binary would be represented as

`00000000 00000000 00000110 10010011`

Now if your machine is little endian it will store the bytes reversing them

`10010011 00000110 00000000 00000000`

`10010011` is at `address 00` `Hypothetical address` ,  `00000110` is at `address 01` and so on.

```
BE:      00   01   02   03
       +----+----+----+----+   
    y: | 00 | 00 | 06 | 93 |
       +----+----+----+----+


LE:      00   01   02   03
       +----+----+----+----+
    y: | 93 | 06 | 00 | 00 |
       +----+----+----+----+

(In Hexadecimal)
```

So now if you dereference `pointer a` it will read only first byte and output will be `-1` as byte read would be `10010011`(Because we pointed `signed char` ,so the `most-significant bit` is the sign bit. First bit `1` denotes the sign. `10010011 = –128 + 16 + 2 + 1 = –109`.) and if you dereference `pointer l` it will completely read all bytes of `int` as we declared it to be pointer to int . And output will be `1234`

And Also if you declare pointer l as `int *l` then `*l` will read `sizeof(int)` usually `4 bytes`(Depends On Machine Architecture) and `*(l+1)` will also read that many bytes . Same goes with `char` or any other data type the pointer pointed to them will read as many bytes there size is of , `char` is of `1 byte`.

Answer (score 6):

The integer `1683` is equal to `0x00000693` (`int` is usually 32 bits on modern systems). On a [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little) system (like x86 and x86-64) it's laid out in memory like

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 0x93 | 0x06 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

When you initialize the pointer `a` you make it point to the first byte in that sequence, the byte which contains the value `0x93`, so that's the value you get when you dereference `a`.

So now to the question on how the value `0x93` becomes `-109`. There are two reasons: One is that `char` with your compiler is `signed` (it's compiler dependent if `char` is a signed or unsigned type). The second reason is because of [*two's complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) arithmetic. [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is a way to be able to encode signed integers on binary machines like modern computers.

Basically, for a single 8-bit byte, you get the negative value by taking the (unsigned) decimal value minus 256 (2<sup>8</sup>). The unsigned decimal value of `0x93` is `147`, and `147 - 256` equals `-109`.

Answer (score 3):

`int` is at least 16-bit, while `char` is always 1 byte ([not necessary 8-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437470/type-to-use-to-represent-a-byte-in-ansi-c89-90-c/437640#437640)). The binary form of number `1683` is `00000110 10010011`. Since you're using `char*`, it will point to the first byte. But then which comes first? Which one will the `char` refers to? `00000110` or `10010011`? It depends:

1) If your system uses little-endian byte order, it will be latter, which is `10010011`.

```
00000110 10010011
         ^^^^^^^^
```

Since you are using **signed** `char` type, the most-significant byte will be used as 'sign-bit', i.e. if it's 1, the byte represents negative number. To get the human-readable value aka base-10 number, you do [two-complement](http://www.tfinley.net/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html). At last you shall get `-109`.

2) If your system uses big-endian byte order, and it uses **16-bit `int`**, it will be former, which is `00000110`. This is easy, the base-10 form of it will be `6`.

```
00000110 10010011
^^^^^^^^
```

If it uses 32-bit `int`, it will be zero:

```
00000000 00000000 00000110 10010011
^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @KeineLust 8-bit == 1 byte

Comment: On big endian machines with 32bit `int` the result would be `0`, not `6`, it would be `6` only with 16 bit `int`.

Comment: @KeineLust oops... my bad... I'm editing it...

Answer (score 2):

Note that `1683 = 0x693`.

If we assume that:

- Your HW architecture is Little-Endian
- Your platform defines `CHAR_BIT` as 8

Then the first `char` in `0x693` is `0x93`.

At this point, note that:

- In `unsigned` 2s-complement format: `0x93 = 147`
- In `signed` 2s-complement format: `0x93 = 147-256 = -109`

Answer (score 1):

The types 'char' and 'int' are different sizes on most platforms. Specifically 'int' is often 32 or 64 bits (4 or 8 bytes) and char only 8 bits (1 byte). When de-referencing a 'char' you are asking the program to "interpret" the memory-location of your 'int' as a 'char'.

Additionally the bytes of an 'int' are stored in memory in either little-endian or big-endian (Google it). Thus the results of your program will differ from platform to platform.

If you are running your code on x86 (which is little-endian), you would possibly see the "correct" value, if you set your 'int' to a value less than 128.

**update:**
As you correctly indicate, the least-significant byte of your int is `10010011` which is `147` decimally and thus *larger than* `10000000` (128 decimal). Since the top-most bit of the byte is set, the value is interpreted as a 2's complement (Google it) negative value of `-109`.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of byte order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

You actually take address of byte `10010011`, which is `-109`.

Comment: Please write answer and do not provide reference as the links can be dead anytime .